# How to repair VisualSVN Server installation

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Our PC that serves the VisualSVN Server 2.5.2 was hacked again. Trying to troubleshoot I deleted *some files*. I am afraid I may have deleted some file related to configuration and may be required by VisualSVN Server. We are no longer able to access the repository from other computers using SVN client or using browser. Can someone help us how we can access it again? The options may be:

1. Do a repair re-installation,
2. Take a backup of the repository, remove & reinstall VisualSVN Server, and import the repository.
3. Some other solution

Comment: What do you mean by 'hacked'? What files did you remove? What errors do you get? What is logged in VisualSVN Server event log?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly did you remove and what do you mean by *"PC was hacked"* the troubleshooting steps may vary.

However if the problem is just about removed files: you can repair VisualSVN Server instance through the **Start | Control Panel | Programs and Features** or by running the *.msi installer of the corresponding version (2.5.2 in your case).

Comment: Well, when I say Hacked, I don't want to move the focus away from the issue. If it helps, half a dozen accounts get created automatically everyday on this WIndows7 system that hosts the server. What I wanted to do is, backup the repository, reinstall the visual SVN server and import the repository. I am novice at that, and don't think the Visual SVN has a visual way of doing it.